# Inaccurate voltage readings on an esp32 as opposed to multimeter

Tags: arduino, multimeter, esp32, lm386

I am working on detecting the amplitude of a signal coming from a guitar pickup. I am using an esp32 and an LM386 module for amplifying the signal.

I get quite stable readings with a multimeter, but the readings on the Arduino IDE show peaks and also peaks come when no signal should be there.

[image: Arduino IDE Readings]

Here is a link for short videos of both the esp32 readings and the multimeter:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gpvkN_sz627jG0TNPpUps82105EB89OF?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Simple code:

```
int ampedVoltagePin = 12;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ampedVoltagePin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(analogRead(ampedVoltagePin));
  delay(100);
}
```

Diagram:

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

0.1 Hz is not enough to measure audible frequencies. You need to get **at least** double the sampling frequency for the signal you measure. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency

Say you have 500 Hz, then you need to sample at least 1000 Hz, or 1 ms.
Then you can attempt peak detection.